# I want to remap a dead key on my old acer laptop

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

My <kbd>D</kbd> key is dead. I want to remap it on my euro sign. But when I run `xev` and I press it nothing appears. It's strange because it works on Windows.

Anyway, in `~/.Xmodmap` I changed the key 122 from <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> to <kbd>D</kbd> and in `~/.xinitrc` from empty to:

```
if [ -f $HOME/.Xmodmap ]; then
    /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
fi
```

But after a restart, the key `Pg up` works as usual. I checked the files and they **did change**. What should I do?